# Running subprocess in a service not working?

Tags: networking, wifi, raspbian-jessie, systemd

I have an automation python script to give a login request to local web server for captive portal wifi hotspot. Sometimes, even the wifi is connected the python login requests is give connection abort error. So I just wanna restart the wifi to have a fresh new connection.

I have made a systemd service in Raspberry Pi with Jessy OS and it is given by.

/etc/systemd/system/caportal.service

```
[Unit]
Description=captive portal automation

[Service]
Type=simple

ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/.caportal/do.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitInterval=2min
```

and /home/pi/.caportal/do.py is given by

```
import subprocess as cm
cm.check_output(['sudo', 'systemctl', 'daemon-reload'])
cm.check_output(['sudo', 'systemctl' ,'restart', 'networking.service'])
cm.check_output(['sudo', 'ifdown', 'wlan0'])
cm.check_output(['sudo', 'ifup', 'wlan0'])
```

Then modified the wpa_supplicant.conf

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="home2"
    psk="pass1234"
    priority=2
}
```

But when i start the service by sudo systemctl start caportal.service, do.py is not working as desired. That is it reconnect the wifi but disconnect when the service stops.

But if i run the python script do.py through the terminal, then the wifi is connected without any problem.

Can anyone help me to find this problem?

Comment: What is the general problem? I can only see that you want to restart the `networking.service` with 4 subprocesses without synchronisation so **ifup** may be finished before **daemon-reload**.

Comment: @Ingo, Its not like that. I have the same problem if I used only the `ifup wlan0` and `ifdown wlan0`.

Comment: @Ingo. I have already tried by replacing the first two commands.

Comment: What is the general problem? Why do you want to restart the `networking.service`?

Comment: I have an automation python script to give a login request to local web server for captive portal wifi hotspot. Sometimes, even the wifi is connected the python login requests is give connection abort error. So I just wanna restart the wifi to have a fresh new connection.

Comment: When do you want to reconnect? Manual when the connection fails?

Comment: I will try to send the requests 4 times. If the requests fail for 4 times, then I will do the wifi restart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98073/discussion-between-ingo-and-mcv).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that when the services terminate, it terminates the child process also. This is the reason why the wifi again goes back to the disconnected state.

When we use wpa_supplicant, there will be a background process running to load the configuration file and it is `/sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -D nl80211,wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

When we run `sudo ifdown wlan0` or `sudo systemctl restart networking`, The above said process will terminate. But when we run `sudo ifup wlan0`, the the above said process will again start in background.

As Ephemeral said, `Your service is terminated (all process started by this service are killed) when your last script (python here) execution is finished.`

Hence I got the answer that, when the service terminates it will kill the `wpa_supplicant background process` and hence the wifi is stop connecting.

So in order to allow the child process to run, there is an option called KillMode.

Hence modified the .service file as follows

```
[Unit]
Description=captive portal automation

[Service]
Type=simple
KillMode=process

ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/.caportal/do.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitInterval=2min
```

Comment: It is pure coincidence that it works. This combination of statements is completely nonsensical in particular with a oneshot bash script that also restarts a service (within this service) that may conflict circular dependencies. I cannot recommend to follow this solution.

Comment: I didn't understand? Can you please tell me the reason why you do not recommend this? I just want to clarify the errors. Can we take the subprocess commands as a child process?

Comment: I don't like to give a tutorial about **systemd**. Please look what [systemd System and Service Manager](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) is and try to understand what you are doing.

Comment: I didn't find a document for killmode and I got this from problem with topic "subprocess exits the child process" from stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry for my rant.. I have been coming down. *Ephemeral* has already taken much effort to help you. But we can try to make a clean service for your problem. But I can't help with Raspbian Jessie. It is outdated. I can only use Raspbian Buster for reference.

Comment: OK Can you give the solution for Raspbian Buster?

Comment: @Ingo. From the documentation, it is given that `If set to process, only the main process itself is killed.` What is the problem when I use this in my script? I am sorry, I am not argue with you. I just want to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Your **service is terminated** (all process started by this service are killed) when your last script (python here) **execution is finished**.

Execute the python script into a terminal, your script exit with default value of 0 (process exit success code) after python file execution because you have not a forever loop (while). Service file is principaly for [daemons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)) control.

**2)** Remove this line : `cm.check_output(['sudo', 'systemctl', 'daemon-reload'])` and use ip command in place to ifup.

**3)** Another script already use wpa_supplicant (**pidof wpa_supplicant**)...

**4)** Use **dmesg** command or show in **syslog** file for any errors...

but that can be so many things.

**If you have not disable** the networking service at start-up (sudo systemctl disable networking.service) then here is what happens:

Comment: How to use ip command instead of ifup?

Comment: `ip link set wlan up` and see my edited answer.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand it. Can you please write the code ? what changes i need to do in do.py?

Comment: what are you trying to do, I do not understand ?

Comment: Actually, do.py has some more codes which request a web page and it will repeat for every 6 hours. Some times internet is disconnected so I need to restart the wifi in the do.py script. But when I included the above piece of code in do.py, wlan0 is restarted and disconnected.

Comment: @Ephermal So I need to restart the wifi in the do.py script to ensure the internet connection.

Comment: @mcv, Do you investigate the loss of connection ? is this a problem with the dhcp client or wpa_supplicant ? Is a service system really necessary ? because if you want to run a script every 6 hours, you can also use [crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) of linux. (but yes it will not solve the connection problem).

Comment: Connection problem solves when we run the script directly through the terminal using command `sudo python /home/pi/.caportal/do.sh`. Now I modified the script with `backgoundscheduler` to repeat for every 6h since service is not working. But really, I wanna know how to run the script through linux service?

Comment: @mcv : `python .../do.sh` ? you call bash script with python or it is just an error here ? You can also call bash script in `ExecStart` in your service, then in this bash script you can do `ping -c 1 stackexchange.com`, if ping failed assume you have not internet access, try to reconnect (call your python script into the bash script). In the bash script implement a `while` loop operation for prevent the service to be stopped when your python script is finish to be executed. Also, you need to attempt the network unit at start-up see : `wants=network-online.target`

Comment: Oh its a typing error

Comment: How can I modify the python script to restart the wifi? Can you please help me?

Comment: @mcv, use wpa_cli (option disconnect or reconnect, [see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314381/how-to-disconnect-from-network-via-wpa-cli))

Comment: As per the answer, I tried `wpa_cli disconnect` and it disconnected the wifi. But when I tried the command `wpa_cli reconnect`, it produce an error `Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null)  error: No such file or directory`

Comment: @mcv, have you put the full line of command line including 'wpa.conf' file and specify the interface name ?

Comment: @mcv, have you put `-i` with the interface name ? –

Comment: Yeah I have figured out the error and it was due to the missing of file `/var/run/wpa_supplicant`. After running the command `wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconnect`, the internet goes down. What should i do to enable it?

Comment: @mcv, maybe you must configure manually the dhcp client. WPA_cli is for the wireless 802.11b/g/n... client. Else , try to use `sudo systemctl restart networking.service` for restarting the full connexion (interface , wifi and dhcp).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to handle an error condition in a python script that is started by a service. If a wifi connection fails you want to reconnect it. You try to manage it with service management but manage services within a service is not a good idea because dependencies and other conditions are handled by different services at the same time and can conflict. The dynamic behavior is unknown.

So you should just manage the wifi connection without services. You can use **wpa_cli** to do it. This program has many commands you can find with `wpa_cli --help | less`. I would start with:

```
rpi ~$ /sbin/wpa_cli -iwlan0 reassociate
```

You can run this command in your python script as subprocess. Here is a simple example how you could use it (executed with `python3 test.py`):

```
import subprocess

subproc = subprocess.run(["/sbin/wpa_cli", "-iwlan0", "reassociate"],
                           capture_output=True, text=True)

if subproc.returncode != 0:
    print(subproc.stderr)
    exit(subproc.returncode)

print(subproc.stdout)
```

If `reassociate` does not help you can try to create a new wifi connection from scratch using **wpa_cli**. How to do it you should find with google.

Comment: running `wpa_cli -i wlan0 reassociate` is not helping me. I have already tried that one. It won't connect to a network. It just reply with OK but nothing is seen on `ifconfig` command for wlan0.

Comment: Also If you want to connect to wifi, you should run `wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure`. This will connect the wifi but the problem is that Rpi will not have the internet.

Comment: At last, I just do `sudo ifdown wlan0` and `sudo ifup wlan0`. This helped me to reconnect to a network and also getting internet.